# Knockout in Dialog to ASP MVC issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am new to KnockoutJS, and am having some issues understanding the best approach to utilize Knockout's databinding.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timotheusg/8c8xhf55/)

My current project uses a dialog popup to then populate things like tables of values.  But currently, I only copy the value over from the dialog to the tables by pushing the values to a Knockout observableArray.  There must be a way to streamline this process some more (I have at least 8 more of these types of dialogs, some with 15+ fields!)

```
<h4>Affiliations</h4>
<table id="AffiliationsTable" data-bind="foreach: affiliations">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Organization Name</td>
            <td>Affiliation Role</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value: OrganizationName, attr: {name: 'Affiliations[' + $index() + '].OrganizationName'}">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value: AffiliationRole, attr: {name: 'Affiliations[' + $index() + '].AffiliationRole'}">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="dialogAffiliation" data-bind="dialog: {autoOpen: false, title: 'Affiliation' }, dialogVisible: isOpen">
    <label for="OrganizationName">Organization Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="OrganizationName" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="OrganizationNameInsert">
    <label for="AffiliationRole">Affiliation Role</label>
    <input type="text" name="AffiliationRole" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="AffiliationRoleInsert"><br />
    <button data-bind="click: addAffiliation">Save</button>
</div>

<div>
    <button data-bind="click: open">Add Affiliations</button>
</div>
```

The KO code is hopefully where the biggest changes would be made, but I can't seem to think of an improvement.  Maybe populating the dialog with an observable that gets moved to the table DOM on save-click.  Or something smarter than that.  Any advice would be appreciated!

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.isOpen = ko.observable(false);
    self.open = function () {
        this.isOpen(true);
    };
    self.close = function () {
        this.isOpen(false);
    };
    self.affiliations = ko.observableArray([
            { OrganizationName: ko.observable('name'), AffiliationRole: ko.observable("role")}, { OrganizationName: ko.observable('name2'), AffiliationRole: ko.observable("role2") }
    ]);

    self.addAffiliation = function () {
        self.affiliations.push({ OrganizationName: document.getElementById("OrganizationNameInsert").value, AffiliationRole: document.getElementById("AffiliationRoleInsert").value });
        $("#dialogAffiliation").dialog('close');
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/timotheusg/8c8xhf55/

Comment: Not the solution you were asking for, but why not simply add the blank fields to the screen? You can bypass opening a modal entirely, and the fields remain editable anyway. Less clicks, better UI (imo).

Comment: A. Boss wants it this way. B. Some fields are going to be transformed into text only (non-editable until clicked) stuff.

Comment: Well... If you must, you could create a model that represents your form/object. Then, using the KOMapping plugin, you could map the data to a new instance of that object and add it to your collection.

Comment: I've added an answer. The team I'm on uses KO to pass models from the client to the server (and vice versa). It may require some playing around with, but there's quite a bit of power behind being able to pass JSON representations of data around, and then cast them as observables, js objects, or as server models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I recommend using models. It allows for consistency, and it adds the benefit of being able to use Knockout's mapping plugin to pass and map the data around.

```
var viewModel = {
    listOfObjects: ko.observableArray(),
    object: {
        affiliation: ko.observable(),
        name: ko.observable(),
        title: ko.observable()

}
```

Have a form bound to "object", and the save button would call a function similar to:

```
// Turn object into plain JS object (there is also a toJSON)
var formData = ko.mapping.toJS(viewmodel.object);
// Push into array
listOfObjects.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(formData, mapping));
```

Reference: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

It's worth noting that you'll need to download and include the mapping plugin's source to be able to use this functionality. It was created by the lead dev of KO, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) avoid using jQuery to muck with the DOM outside of the bindingHandler. Have an object in your view model whose observables the dialog inputs bind to. Then when you push that object into your list, you can create a new, clean input object.

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.isOpen = ko.observable(false);
    self.open = function () {
        this.isOpen(true);
    };
    self.close = function () {
        this.isOpen(false);
    };

    function newAffiliation(name, role) {
        return {
            OrganizationName: ko.observable(name),
            AffiliationRole: ko.observable(role)
        };
    }

    self.affiliations = ko.observableArray([
    newAffiliation('name1', 'role1'),
    newAffiliation('name2', 'role2')]);

    self.dialogAffiliation = ko.observable(newAffiliation());

    self.addAffiliation = function () {
        self.affiliations.push(self.dialogAffiliation());
        self.dialogAffiliation(newAffiliation());
        self.close();
    };
};
```

You can eliminate the `update` portion of the binding handler by having the widget subscribe to your `isOpen` element.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

        /* .... stuff you wrote .... */   
        allBindingsAccessor().dialogVisible.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            $el.dialog(newValue ? 'open' : 'close');
        });

        /* ... more stuff you wrote ...*/

    }
};
```

I updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8c8xhf55/1/). I got rid of id attributes because you don't need to search for them. I got rid of name attributes because they're cluttery in the code, but you may have a reason to want them.